# Microsoft Graph - Get MemberOf error with application token

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying access Microsoft Graph API to query list of groups a user belongs to, using the below endpoint

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userID}/memberOf

But since last two days, my queries are failing with below response

```
{   error: {
    code: 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
    message: 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.',
    innerError: {
      'request-id': '7d8a5602-19ca-4cc7-a84d-60cc0c9c09d5',
      date: '2020-04-28T11:44:24'
    }   } }
```

I already have required permission and concent granted as admin, the access rights I gave include

```
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Group.Read.All
```

As mentioned in microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

[image]

The API request is being sent with the autorization header of access token (from service) following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Decoded JWT Token being passed in the authorization header:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/TENANTID_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY/",
  "iat": 1588150105,
  "nbf": 1588150105,
  "exp": 1588154005,
  "aio": "42dgYOCaN0c46++enU1fZx+98Lc3DQA=",
  "app_displayname": "dspIT",
  "appid": "MYAPPID_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/TENANTID_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY/",
  "oid": "fc709ea2-887e-4794-9417-ac578ab825e8",
  "rh": "0.ATEAfGSULqtSkUqIuFyy2LRFJyPSTnvDYjVDlpuh_cMocSgxAAA.",
  "roles": [
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "RoleManagement.Read.Directory",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.Create",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Invite.All",
    "Directory.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "GroupMember.Read.All",
    "User.Export.All",
    "PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureADGroup",
    "User.ManageIdentities.All",
    "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory",
    "GroupMember.ReadWrite.All",
    "Group.Selected",
    "PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup"
  ],
  "sub": "fc709ea2-887e-4794-9417-ac578ab825e8",
  "tid": "TENANTID_REMOVED_FOR_SECURITY",
  "uti": "wvHXdAZomUefp2RpSGBPAA",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1519129156
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please decode your access token in https://jwt.io/ to see what "roles" it includes? Please share a screenshot if it's convenient.

Comment: Hi Kumar Vivek, are you facing this issue with the West Europe region? I am also facing this issue only in West Europe region. It is working fine in UK South

Comment: @AllenWu thanks for coming forward to help, I updated the question with encoded JWT token being passed with the API request.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava Azure AD properties suggest its hosted in "Germany" with "EU Model Clause compliant datacenters"

Comment: Hi Kumar Vivek, I don't know about Germany but I am accessing the same endpoint via Azure functions hosted in West Europe and it is not working. I am getting the same error. But when I deployed the same Azure function to UK South or North Europe, it is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Kumar Vivek, it is not working in Germany either.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava our AKS where the service is running is from west europe and maybe thats why its failing. Thanks for confirming that issuse is also from Germany region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your Decoded JWT Token, I did a quick test and have found the reason.

There seems to be an Application permission `Group.Selected` that affects the calling of this API endpoint `/memberOf`.

There is something wrong with this permission and it has affected some other endpoint. I answered a similar post before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60985658/running-into-serviceunavailable-sharepoint-graph-query-forever-when-combining/61117018#61117018).

So if it's not necessary, just remove it from your Azure AD application. Then this error will disappear.

If this permission is needed, I'm afraid you need to create a new Azure AD app to add the permission in it for using.

Comment: Hi Allen, if that is the case then why the same application having the same configuration but deployed in another region working perfectly?

Comment: @Allen it worked. Thanks! We will investigate what are the dependency due to this role but for now we are able to query the memberOf groups after removing this permission.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava I'm not sure about it. Are you sure you have `Group.Selected` included in your access token and it can still work fine in your region?

Comment: @KumarVivek Np:). Glad to know it's helpful.

Comment: Hi Allen, yes I am sure about it. I didn't change anything

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava It seems that the change of `Group.Selected` doesn't affect all the regions. You could raise a support ticket on Azure portal for further investigation. Anyway, if you have this issue, just remove/separate it for the time being.

Comment: @Allen Yeah I removed that permission for testing, thanks to you for identifying it and already opened a support ticket to Microsoft.